# crypto.publicEncrypt equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption

Im trying to encrypt a string from a PHP application to a NodeJS API using a public key.

So far in node I am using the built-in crypto library and have the following code to decrypt a string:

```
decrypt(toDecrypt): string {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(toDecrypt, "base64");
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
      {
        key: this.privateKey,
        passphrase: this.passphrase
      },
      buffer
    );

    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
  }
```

I have been looking for a while now and cannot find an equivalent PHP code that will run through the node application and decrypt correctly.
My keys are generated using:

```
const keys = await generateKeyPairSync("rsa", {
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
          type: "spki",
          format: "pem"
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
          type: "pkcs8",
          format: "pem",
          cipher: "aes-256-cbc",
          passphrase: this.passphrase
        }
      });
```

EDIT:

The PHP code that I am using currently:

```
<?PHP


$text = "TEST";

$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA6x5nGicq8jWbjRfeCot3
83M9Jo6wzhVAX9kKvIaKA51dR60qKKVXc8rJ3mWJIBsnWmEy1/QZ4BtEZ13ISFbt
DMzwMfV99hD12XqCvU1b45l//87Rqs1rE+7G90mW53mq5u2jmP/+7SCX+5r9ASLX
pJOoXRIpJpJhh/molv0PxS9b5c7nkrhGhpgQ1QeUSc3Q25kFP5PbAhphx08/M/KO
MaeBn+W4mhdS4Pt1Wgqa0T5PKkzr/uHd68f7IDqYWNKC9dMg0J2Rw8mo7g4L1oid
k/GkHk0UcSAe6FY5dsExgTMAEYwW7ngbPEQ8/BofGHWSnNVDFvuDxjCHAp+IEYa7
s3f+YmKqjoDDHkmx5kCYHYi+BK/gba3CLRfbvzlcd2YjOZZ8Mvd+1CBzYK5blyDv
Sefz8Kj+qmMOV9P4B9x4yVHGA57+vGmSbpEkdVUVd3JaazZFBSaiI8yQPeeljjze
0GH3V0BAPi3awCHVLYnbUJ1s0Q40RrEvWZQNjHGm17oHM0yfzgMUldJmUD6XGSOO
jJbfyAR4/TizosVedQ9CazTAogzFyqUtP74dzcNeHezKHz9ILngYTYuUT8p+wEIT
KejP5QqD/yumtUTNOYS/5fTvuTa7e97m0SgjlNHikol/DPcjz5RTf/tLxyVAft7I
3X5yUC7gDLdXBONMzhIA8YsCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($key);

$output = "";
openssl_public_encrypt($text, $output, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
echo base64_encode($output) . PHP_EOL;
```

EDIT2:

What PHP Script gives me:

```
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
```

Error that Node gives me:
[image]

Can somebody please help?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I don't see any code where you tried, so I won't answer. But note this from the crypto-js documentation: "If it is an object, the padding property can be passed. Otherwise, this function uses RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING." Most libraries default to PKCS#1 v1.5 padding instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @MaartenBodewes I have added the PHP I am using to generate the encrypted text, For the encryption function PHP side I am using the param: OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, in NodeJS you *are* using the private key of the same key pair as the public key, right? What does your PHP code do? Can you print out what you get and how NodeJS fails to decrypt (error, mangled plaintext)?

Comment: Thanks again @MaartenBodewes Yes the public and private keys are both generated at the same by the function described above. Let me know if you need anymore information

Comment: Still, this is the error you get when the public / private keys are not of the same pair. Both libs seem to use OAEP with SHA-1 as hash function configured for OAEP, so this does surprise me. I don't see any other option really. Sorry, gotta log out :|

Comment: No problem, @MaartenBodewes Thanks for the help! Appreciate it